# Creating boxplot of MAM that has two categorical explanatory variables

Tags: boxplot, lmer

I am trying to create graphical representation of my MAM which is explained by two categorial variables. I realise I need to make 2 boxplot to show the effect of each explanatory variable as the interaction between the two is insignificant. How do I graph the boxplots as I can't seem to extract the means etc and Im not sure if its because I am using an lmer.

Here is my code so far....

```
m1<-lmer(Bird.species~Weather*AM.or.PM+(1|Staff),family=poisson)
summary(m1)
m2<-update(m1,REML=FALSE)
m3<-update(m2,~.-Weather:AM.or.PM)
anova(m2,m3)
m4<-update(m3,~.-Weather)
anova(m3,m4)
m5<-update(m3,~.-AM.or.PM)
anova(m3,m5)

m6<-update(m5,~.-Weather)
anova(m5,m6)
m7<-update(m4,~.-AM.or.PM)
anova(m4,m6)

mam.lmer<-update(m3,REML=TRUE)
summary(mam.lmer)
```

I think in order to plot the two graphs I have to use m4 for AM or PM, and m5 for weather.

I have this so far but then get stuck and can't seem to find the answer anywhere that helps as when I use "$" it creates errors I dont underrstand.

```
m5<-update(m5,REML=TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
mam.graph1<-update(m5,~.-1)
```

thanks